# Backbone 1.0 reset vs sync event

Tags: backbone.js

```
PgaPlayersApp.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#pga_players_profile_app',
    initialize: function()
    {
        //Should I do 1?
        this.listenTo(PgaPlayersApp.Players, 'sync', this.addAll);

        //Should I do 2?
        this.listenTo(PgaPlayersApp.Players, 'reset', this.addAll);

        PgaPlayersApp.Players.fetch({reset: true});
    }
});
```

In the above code example, what is the preferred method for listening to a fetch for a collection? (sync or reset)

Comment: it depends... could you elaborate?

Comment: Could you let me know what it depends on? I will be doing pagination with fetch (not sure how I am doing to do this yet, as I am new to backbone). But for now fetch is called on page load.

Comment: In your example itself it's quite the same. However, you have to be aware that if you listen to `sync`, your listener will be executed each time you make a REST call, not only when you fetch.

Answer (score 2):

You should listen for `'sync'`. This is the event fired on a successful fetch operation. A `'reset'` is now only fired when an explicit `collection.reset(newModels)` is called. `'sync'` is consistent between collections and models now, which is a nice consistency.

FYI: http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-93